If $\mu_n {\rightharpoonup}\mu$, then under what conditions $|\mu_n - \mu | {\rightharpoonup} 0$?
Let $(X,\mathcal{B})$ be a measurable space where $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$,compact, $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel sigma algebra, $\mu$ is a finite signed measure.
Let $\left\langle \mu_n\right\rangle_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of finite signed measures $\mu_n: \mathcal{B} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that $\mu_n \rightarrow \mu$ weakly, i.e.,$\int f \mathrm{~d} \mu_n \rightarrow \int f \mathrm{~d} \mu$ for all continuous bounded functions $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
My question is, can we say anything about the sequence of measures $|\mu_n - \mu|$? Are there additional natural conditions under which this sequence converges to the zero measure? Any comments, examples and counterexamples are most appreciated.

Someone at least explain why the downvote so I can improve the question for everyone's benefit!

As the name itself suggests, weak convergence is too weak for convergence in total variation. There are no useful sufficient conditions either.
